# How to hide silverlight control inside CRM with javascript call?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, dynamics-crm

In crm i'm rendering a Silverlight control to render some tasks in a pretty look and feel for the current entity.

I was wondering how I can hide the Silverlight control when there are no tasks...

When there are no tasks, the Silverlight control shows nothing. But the space that is reserved for the silverlight object remains in the html.

How can I achieve this? Is there some sort of method like

Application.Current.Host.Content.Hide() ... ?

Comment: Hiding the Silverlight Control might not be enough if there is a `DIV` in the page that still reserves the space. Check the HTML too.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/12/Silverlight-Apps-that-Resize-Themselves.html

It explains very well how everything works together (HTML and Silverlight)